# How to show that there exists x that belongs to [a,b] such that g(x)=x where g: [a,b] -> [a,b] is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

In my textbook the question before this asks me to state the Mean Value theorem so I think that might be a way to go about this problem. But I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x):=g(x)-x$.

Show that: $f(a) \ge 0$ and $ f(b) \le 0$

Your turn !

Comment: can you give me some hints on how to proceed i.e. using which theorem ?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem

Comment: But I do not know the value of a and b to evaluate f(x)

Comment: We have $f(a) \ge 0$ and $f(b) \le 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$, hence $g(x)=x$